# How can I use the amount variable outside this function please can any one help me

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Please can anyone tell me how can I get the amount variable or its data which I am fetching from `req.body` outside of the this function?

```
app.post("/pay", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body); 
  const { amount , description , name } = req.body;    //this is that amount variable
  const create_payment_json = {
    intent: "sale",
    payer: {
      payment_method: "paypal",
    },
    redirect_urls: {
      return_url: "http://localhost:3000/success",
      cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/cancel",
    },
    transactions: [
      {
        item_list: {
          items: [
            {
              name: name,
              sku: "001",
              price: amount,
              currency: "USD",
              quantity: 1,
            },
          ],
        },
        amount: {
          currency: "USD",
          total: amount,
        },
        description: description,
      },
    ],
  };

  paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
        if (payment.links[i].rel === "approval_url") {
          res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);
        }
      }
    }
  });
});

app.get("/success", (req, res) => {
  const payerId = req.query.PayerID;
  const paymentId = req.query.paymentId;

  const execute_payment_json = {
    payer_id: payerId,
    transactions: [
      {
        amount: {
          currency: "USD",
          total: amount,    // I want it here also
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  paypal.payment.execute(
    paymentId,
    execute_payment_json,
    function (error, payment) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
        ;
      } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
        res.send("Success");
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: I don't quite understand.  This is a request callback for what looks like an express server.  Where else would you expect to use the request data?  Show your client-side function that actually calls the `fetch` if that's what you are asking about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @zero298 i have comment where i want that amount variable data now please if you can help me

Comment: Can you also show how you want to use it outside of this function?  We don't need a ton of detail, but we do need an [mre].

Comment: i want to use the value in app.get("/success", (req, res))

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear from your question, but it seems like you just want to have access to `amount` from outside the response callback.  If it is as plain as that, you just need to have a place for it in a higher scope.  For example, I'm going to store all the payments in a `payments` array.  I'm also renaming "ammount" to "amount" (it's misspelled).

Whenever a `POST` is made to `app.post("/pay")`, we push a payment.  `payments` is available to `app.get("/success")` because it is in a higher scope.

If this isn't what you are trying to do, you need to add more details to your question and explain exactly what isn't working.

### `index.js`

```
import express from "express";

const app = express();

const payments = [];

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world");
});

app.get("/success", (req, res) => {
  console.log(`There have been ${payments.length} payments`);
  if (payments.length) {
    const {person, amount, time} = payments[payments.length - 1];
    console.log(`Last payment was ${amount} by ${person} @ ${time}`);
  }
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.post("/pay", (req, res) => {
  const {person, amount} = req.body;
  const time = Date.now();

  payments.push({person, amount, time});
  console.log(`${person} paid ${amount} @ ${time}`);

  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(3002, () => {
  console.log("Listening");
});
```

This is the file that I used to test with.  It uses [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) as a `fetch` polyfill.

### `test.js`

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const sleep = (t=1000) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, t));

const main = async () => {
  const payResponse = await fetch("http://localhost:3002/pay", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      person: "Bob Barker",
      amount: 500
    })
  });

  await sleep();

  const checkResponse = await fetch("http://localhost:3002/success");
};

main()
  .then(() => console.log("Done"))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Running it produces this:

```
Listening
Bob Barker paid 500 @ 1631202912836
There have been 1 payments
Last payment was 500 by Bob Barker @ 1631202912836
```